# http post callback not working angular factory

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-services

I am trying to get a callback from the angular service but the callback function does not work.

Here is My controller code:-

```
$scope.uu = "hello"  // this i just make for test
$scope.login = function(user){
    //console.log(user)
    AuthenticationService.Login(user.username,user.password).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.uu = data;
    })
}
```

My service code is:-

```
    mainApp.service('AuthenticationService',function($http,$cookieStore,$rootScope){
    var service = {};
    service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

            $http({
        method: "POST",
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: 'users/authenticate',
        data: {email: username,password:password}
    })
    .success(callback);
        };
        return service;
});
```

Neither I get response in console. Neither the scope is changed.
I have referred to this question but the answer is not working for me.
[$http POST response from service to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358090/http-post-response-from-service-to-controller)

Comment: Check what error you are getting while making API call

Comment: I am getting correct response from api. the api is responding.

Comment: only the callback is not working, even if I write console.log('test'), that does not work too in controller

Comment: callback is a function or parameter where you using?

Comment: see the code above

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA I am not sure, but hide API call code and first see controller is working or not.

Comment: Controller is working, have you read my code.

Comment: have you checked the linked problem, i have linked problem reference.

Comment: change service to factory see if it works

Comment: Thanks @ricky it worked.. can you explain the reason.

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA please see the answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing service your code should look like this :

```js
mainApp.service('AuthenticationService',function($http,$cookieStore,$rootScope){
    
    this.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

            $http({
        method: "POST",
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: 'users/authenticate',
        data: {email: username,password:password}
    })
    .success(callback);
        };
        
});
```

Always remember service is just like prototype function
We should not return object in cas of service. Angular Instantiate the object and return automatically