# Angular Services return function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

In the following two examples I am using 2 different structures for service return. While first I am returning the function in braces, in second I am returning function by function name. According to me both should work fine.

While Case 1 works, Case 2 fails. Can someone explain why?

**Case 1**

```js
// module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, baseService ){
$scope.name = "Peter";
var a = baseService.helloFunction()
 console.log(a);
});

// services declaration
app.service('baseService', function($http){
return{
 // For Rating Chart 
 helloFunction: function() {
  return "Hello";
 }

}

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Case 2:**

```js
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, baseService ){
$scope.name = "Peter";
var a = baseService.helloFunction()
 console.log(a);
});

// services declaration
app.service('baseService', function($http){

// For Rating Chart 
helloFunction: function() {
 return "Hello";
}

return helloFunction();

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

In this, while Case 1 works fine, Case 2 fails! While in both cases in service structure I am returnign inner function in outer function. Why doesn't case 2 works?

Comment: first one is `service` second one is `factory`

Comment: posibble duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425879/http-post-callback-not-working-angular-factory/41426270#41426270

Comment: Both are factories only.

Comment: No, completely different question that was.

Comment: but the solution you are looking for is same

Comment: But, as javascript I just have to return inner function. I am doing same thing in both cases. The answer cannot explain the error or why is it coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You case 2 has syntactical errors and You are returning the output of the function `helloFunction`. As you are invoking it.

Since `string` does't have `helloFunction()` function it throws the error.

Here the snippet.

```js
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, baseService) {
  $scope.name = "Peter";
  var a = baseService.helloFunction()
  console.log(a);
});

// services declaration
app.service('baseService', function($http) {
  // For Rating Chart 
  this.helloFunction = function() {
    return "Hello";
  }
});

//Or, Create factory
app.fatory('baseService2', function($http) {
  // For Rating Chart 
  var helloFunction = function() {
    return "Hello";
  }
  return {
    helloFunction: helloFunction
  };
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: your code snippet in not correct. service does not suppose to return any explicit object in angular

Answer (score 2):

You service code should look like this

```js
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, baseService ){
$scope.name = "Peter";
var a = baseService.helloFunction()
 console.log(a);
});

// services declaration
app.service('baseService', function($http){

// For Rating Chart 
this.helloFunction: function() {
 return "Hello";
}
  
});
```

Or  the way you are using is suppose to be factory

```js
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, baseService ){
$scope.name = "Peter";
var a = baseService.helloFunction()
 console.log(a);
});

// services declaration
app.factory('baseService', function($http){

return { 
helloFunction: function() {
 return "Hello";
}

  }


});
```

Services are like prototype function no need to return explicitly and in case of factory you return the object.